# Encoding information in the CMB

Tags: big-bang, cosmic-microwave-background

Given that a civilization had the capability (Kardashev type IV?), and supposing Ω > 1, would it be possible to adjust the universe in a way that would effectively encode information in the CMB before your pending demise and the next big bang?

What I am curious to ascertain by asking this question is if we know it's possible for information to survive the big crunch (if perhaps the mode of our universe previous to the big bang was a big crunch and not heat death) or if that theoretical singularity would cause the erasure of all information.

Comment: There are a few contender theories for predicting what the [ultimate fate of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_fate_of_the_universe) will be. We don't know which of those will be the definite way(s) for the universe to end, although the current observations arguably tilt the opinion in favor of Heath Death of the universe.  So, to be succinct, with no observational data to predict the existence of a civilisation and their capabilities, much less know about the possible ways that the death and the rebirth of the universe can be engineered, we'd only be left with speculations.

Comment: I think, yes, by definition. Although the CMB was created long ago, if you can control the energy production of the whole Universe, you can also adjust it. The problem is that it is not really a physics question, but it is an interesting question.

Comment: I have voted to close because this seems to be asking about science fiction rather than mainstream physics. The possibility of altering the universe is either science fiction or engineering, and nobody knows how the condition of the universe at its demise will alter the next big bang.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the possible capabilities of a hypothetical entity and not at all physics.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this guys, I've added a clarification that what I'm curious about is if we know if any information could survive the big bang singularity.

Comment: @sammygerbil I've updated my question. Would you think of tossing a reopen vote?

Comment: @KyleKanos Would you consider reopening?

Comment: This is a legitimate question - within a cosmology or physical theory in which there is a "next big bang" (e.g. bounce cosmology, or theories in which black holes create baby universes). It could be posed as follows: if one allows coordinated actions on an astronomical or cosmic scale, can they leave a trace or imprint in the new universe? But you may have to ask someone who actually has such a theory.